# How to access status code in a http call using Retrofit package?

Tags: flutter, dart, retrofit

retrofit takes a `dio` object so how can access that dio object to access the status code like `200` or something like this,

**Retrofit base class**

```
@RestApi(baseUrl: 'url')
abstract class ApiService {
  factory ApiService({Dio dio, String baseUrl}) {
    return _ApiService(dio, baseUrl: baseUrl);
  }

  @GET('/user')
  Future<List<Plant>> getUser(
    @Query('userId') String id,
  );
}
```

**repositoy**

```
class Repository {
  Dio dio = Dio();
  ApiService apiService;

  Repository() {
    dio = Dio();
    dio.interceptors.add(HeaderInterceptor());
    apiService = ApiService(
        dio: dio,
       baseUrl: 'http://10.0.2.2:8080/api',
        );
  }



  Future<User> getFloorPlanById(String id) async {
    try {
      final user = await apiService.getUser(id);
      return user;
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

I want to access status code here so that I can show different types of screen based on status code.

If I directly use it then I have to call api again so that doesn't make sense.

so How can access status code here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two ways to do this,

**Method-1**

use `DioError`

```
on DioError catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());

    }
```

here `e` contains the status code you can use it

**Method-2**

use `HttpResponse`

make the return type `HttpResponse` of API call function

ex-:

```
Future<HttpResponse> getUser(
    @Query('userId') String id,
  );
```

the result will contain the data along side the status code and message

Comment: In Method 1: status code is only returned if it's an error.
In Method 2: how do I get my JSON parsed value response?